# ffmpeg configuration difficulty with filter_complex and hls

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to set up ffmpeg so that it will record from a microphone and encode the results at the same time into a .flac file for later syncing up with some video I will be making.

The microphone is plugged into a raspberry pi (4B) and I am currently trying it with a blue yeti mic, but I think I can do the same with a focusrite scarlett 2i2 plugged in instead.  However I was puzzling about how to start the server recording and decided I could do it from a web browser if I made a simple nodejs server that spawned ffmpeg as a child process.

But then I was inspired by this sample ffmpeg command which displays (on my desktop with an graphical interface) a volume meter

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i 'http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4' -filter_complex "showvolume=rate=25:f=0.95:o=v:m=p:dm=3:h=80:w=480:ds=log:s=2" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -f mpegts - | ffplay -window_title "Peak Volume" -i -
```

What if I could stream the video produced by the `showvolume` filter to the web browser that I am using to control the ffmpeg process (NOTE I don't want to send the audio with this).  So I tried to read up on hls (since the control device will be an ipad - in fact that is what I will record the video on), and came up with this command

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -f alsa -ac 2 -ar 48k -i hw:CARD=Microphone -filter_complex "asplit=2[main][vol],[vol]showvolume=rate=25:f=0.95:o=v:m=p:dm=3:h=80:w=480:ds=log:s=2[vid]" -map [main] -c:a:0 flac recordings/session_$(date +%a_%d_%b_%Y___%H_%M_%S).flac -map [vid] -preset veryfast -g 25 -an -sc_threshold 0 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 2000k -maxrate:v:1 2200k -bufsize:v:3000k -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags independent_segments delete_segments -strftime 1 -hls_segment_filename recordings/volume-%Y%m%d-%s.ts recordings/volume.m3u8
```

The problem is I am finding the documentation a bit opaque as to what happens once I have generated two streams - the main audio and a video stream, and this command throws both a warning and an error:-

The warning is `Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo`

and the error is

```
[NULL @ 0x1baa130] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'hls'
hls: Invalid argument
```

What I am trying to do is set up stream labels [main] and [vol] as I split the incoming audio into two parts, then I pass [vol] through the "showvolume" filter and end up with stream [vid].

I think I need to then use `-map` to specify encoding the [main] stream down to flac and writing it out to file (The file exists after I run the command although they have zero length), and use another -map to pass through to the `-f hls` section.  But I think I have something wrong at this stage.

Can someone help me get this command right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-bufsize:v:3000k` is likely a typo, try `-bufsize:v:1 3000k`

Comment: Almost there but not quite.  It ran for a while (until I pressed control C), the only problem was as well as `volume.m3u8` and some segments in `recordings`, the directory above had what looked like the same `hls` files called `delete_segments`

Comment: My bad - i missed on the `:1` on the `-bufsize:v:1` and I had two flags on `-hls_flags` then second one being called `delete_segments`.  Not sure if `-hls_flags` only has one argument and whether I need to repeat it to add another.  Anyway it seems to be working